# codeigniter routes use the same controller passed in the url but different method

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I the application i am building there are multiple controller where everyone inherits from my_controller hence if it specify a certain method no matter which controller i want it access a method which is in the my_controller hence it has it be in such a way that it takes the controller name from the url and the method which i specify

```
$route['(:any)/reoprt_performance'] = "same_controller_as_url/performance";
```

the same controller which is passed in the url should be used.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand correctly your question, but are you looking for something like this?

```
$route['same_controller/(:any)'] = 'same_controller/$1';
```

Comment: no the thing is my controller may change but the method remains same so the controller has to be taken from the url and the method i will specify

Comment: But if you change controllers, how it will pick up the same method?

Comment: i have multiple controller where everyone inherits from my_controller hence all have the method but any controller may be accessing the method

Answer (score 0):

sorry the way is this

```
$route['(:any)/reoprt_performance'] = "$1/performance";
```